# SAS Proc IML: Length of a vector

Tags: sas, proc

If I have a matrix that is say 10X2 and would to store in SAS the value of the length of the matrix (hence 10) under another variable...how is it done in PROC IML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have NROW and NCOL functions, is that what you're looking for?

```
proc iml;
a= {1 2, 2 5, 3 6, 4 1};
r = NROW(a);
c = NCOL(a);
print r c;
quit;
```

Comment: superb thanks! I don't know why but I looked every where online for "length of vector PROC IML" and nothing! Its so basic... anyhow thanks a lot!